# Sims 4 Graphics glitch?

Tags: the-sims-4

So I bought Sims 4 and even with the Create A Sim demo it did this across all my computers, I don't know what is wrong. Any help? I have an quad core Intel processor up to 3.5 GHz, 16 GB RAM and a 8GB NVidia GeForce graphics card in my laptop.
[image: My screen]

Comment: I am making the assumption that this question was reposed after you deleted your previous question (which i can't view due to lack of rep) which had a score of -3 or more since you have the [Peer Pressure Badge](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure), please don't delete and repost down-voted questions just to reset the vote count, review your question instead

Comment: It was reposted due to lack of views/reponses.

Comment: Another reason you should not delete and repost, according to my cached version of the question's list, your original question was post 3-4 hours ago, for me being in Australa that was about 9 in the morning but for other that's close to midnight. If someone can answer your question they will find it, hell, someone may be about ready to answer you question after researching for a while but got an error when they went to post because you deleted it (can post on deleted answer)

Comment: @RyanBlack That's generally a rather bad reason to repost questions here.  We are happy to help, but we're not a forum, and deleting and reposting isn't a very good way to gather attention.

Comment: I am the same as Memor-X, being in Australia, there is a lull in answering and question posting. You will get an answer, but if you're that impatient, talk to EA. Though I doubt you would have as much luck, being EA and all...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your graphic card drivers are up to date. If it doesnt fix it, try to change some launch settings by right clicking and going in the property menu of your shortcut.

if it doesnt work, contact EA. They are probably already aware of this problem and might already have a temporary fix so you can play while the next bug fix comes out.

Comment: My computer is up to date in regards to drivers, I tried the launch settings adjustments however I still get nothing.  After waiting for and installing the recent updates I still receive the same issue.

Comment: @BreakinDragon Could you paste a DxDiag report to your question? This could help me find whats wrong. This is how you can get a DxDiag Report: [link](http://www.matrixgames.com/support/faq.asp?id=22). Do you have other graphical problems with other games? have you tried with another game that require a more powerfull graphic card?

Comment: I will post it whenever I can get to my main PC.  This is the only game I have an issue with graphically, and most of my other games are far more demanding than Sims 4, its coming from Origin so I do not know the issue.