# Sims 4 Pixellated Graphics problem

Tags: the-sims-4

I just purchased the Sims 4 - digital download. When the came opens the graphics are completely off - reminds of a DOS game and I can barely make out the screen. I am on a laptop and my system meets the requirements for the game. I tried to put the game in laptop mode but can barely make out the screen so its hard to make sure I'm selecting the right option. HELP!

Comment: Welcome to the site, ksir! Can you give us some more information about the specs of your machine?

Comment: And please provide a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183080/sims-4-graphics-glitch (at least his deleted answer on that question would lead me to believe).

Comment: @DavidB don't think so - "reminds me of a DOS game" makes me think it's a pirate copy - see my answer :D

Comment: It's like @franglais said. The issue you're having looks like the built-in piracy countermeasure of Sims 4. The best you can do is get in touch with EA's customer support and see how they can help. There should be no problem if you really bought the game legitimately.

Answer (score 10):

There is an anti-piracy measure in the Sims 4 that makes the whole game become pixallated. My guess is that this is the issue and you did not in fact purchase the game legally.

[image: Pixellated Sims]

[Source](http://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2014/09/04/the-sims-4-punishes-pirates-by-pixelating-the-entire-game/)

Comment: Wow, that's sneaky. Even for EA.

Comment: @psyk0 hilarious I think is the word you are looking for!

Comment: While it's true there might be a chance the OP wasn't entirely honest with us and actually did pirate the game, there have always been instances where legitimately purchased software unleash their anti-piracy measures against their honest purchasers. If the OP really did buy the game, he should have absolutely no trouble getting in touch with EA support to find a solution.

Comment: This (the mosaic) showing up on legitimate users has been known as a bug. The thing with this is that less than half of the users getting the mosaic pirated the game before actually buying it. But from what I've heard, it may have already been fixed.